# Provide a mean to reset a specific Hyper-V guest

Tags: hyper-v

We are hosting a Hyper-V Server on Windows Server(r) Enterprise. The access to this server is done by Remote Desktop connections. When one users is connected and a new RDP session is established the former user is kicked off by the new connection.

There is often the task to reset a specific guest VM in Hyper-V. How can this VM turned off/on without kicking off the current RDP session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a different tool. If you're not using SCVMM then you can try these:

http://www.probus-it.se/hypervtools/hypervmanager

http://www.5nine.com/5nine-manager-for-hyper-v-free.aspx